# If(condition) else or if(condition), is there a difference in performance when using break?

Tags: java, performance, if-statement

The question is a little bit ambiguous, are these two equivalent in assembly code/performance wise:

```
public void example{
  do{
     //some statements;
     if(condition) break;
     //some statements;
  }while(true);
}
```

versus:

```
public void example{
  do{
     //some statements;
     if(condition){ 
     break;
     }else{
     //some statements;
     }
  }while(true);
}
```

Comment: It depends on the compiler, and will probably look the same, did you try to look at the assembly of those options?

Comment: the answer is that, no, there shouldn't be a performance difference (assuming an intelligently designed compiler). the necessary comparison for the conditional was already done, so there isn't an additional performance cost for the "else".
i don't have a source to back myself up, that's why i'm commenting instead of answering.

Comment: There is no chance it would ever be worth the effort optimising between these two choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are equivalent and they should result in the same bytecode representation. Therefore performance-wise, they are the same.

`if`, `else` and `break` are branch instructions. In this case, `break` would terminate the loop and the program goes to a different branch. If the condition is not met, another branch is taken, which is *exactly* the same branch taken by the `else`.

Example using the `javac` compiler:

```
int a = System.in.read();
do {
    System.out.println("a");
    if (a > 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("b");
    }
} while (true);
```

Both this and without the `else` produce the following:

```
getstatic java/lang/System/in Ljava/io/InputStream;
invokevirtual java/io/InputStream/read()I
istore_1
getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;            :label1
ldc "a"
invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
iload_1
ifle <label2>
goto <label3>
getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;            :label2
ldc "b"
invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
goto <label1>
return                                                          :label3
```

Comment: It *should*, but does it? It's not a trivial optimization for the compiler to make.

Comment: Tried it on Oracle javac and it results in the exact same bytecode.

Comment: @Juhana i can't think of any reason it wouldn't be trivial. as to whether it actually does result in the same bytecode, the answer would be dependent on the compiler (so it would have to be tested on a per-compiler basis).